# Word for a person who hates India

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

**[Anglophobe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anglophobe)** is the word for a person who hates England. Oxford Dictionaries defines it as

> **noun** A person having a strong dislike of England or Britain.

Is there a similar word for a person who hates India?

Comment: Head over to electronics.stackexchange with the endless flood of poorly researched homework questions and you will find quite a few of these.. :/

Comment: @pipe I'm intrigued!!

Comment: Pretty sure this can be trivially looked up in any general reference, or even Stack Overflow where it seems common enough.  See also [the evolution of the modern anti-Indian movement in North America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Indian_sentiment).

Comment: I don't suppose it matters that the name of the country is _Bharat_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One could form a neologism "*misindicist*" or "*misindist*". Technically, "*-phobe*" refers to one who fears (not hates) something; "*mis-*" refers to hatred (not fear) of something. Thus, "*misindicist*" would be formed in a similar vein as "misogynist" or "misanthrope".

Comment: _"Technically, '-phobe' refers to one who fears (not hates) something"_ That is not true, despite the original meaning of the root.

Comment: _Misindi(ci)st_ may be well-formed and etymologically sound, but it would be extremely unlikely to be understood by anyone.

Comment: While this is indeed less likely to be understood than _Indophobe_, I do agree that it is more correct. _Mis-_ is indeed still used more to denote hate, whereas _-phobia_ indicates mostly fear. A misogynist doesn't necessarily _fear_ women, and an aviophobe usually doesn't hate planes (but just fears having to travel in one).

Comment: (But _Anglophobia_ is certainly common and does rather mean _hate against Britain_ rather than _fear of the British_.)

Comment: But if you dedicate _misindicist_ to "a person who hates India," what would you call a person who dislikes indexes?

Answer (score 40):

The combining form of ‘India’ is *Indo-*, so the obvious answer is ***Indophobe/Indophobia***.

This isn’t exactly a widely used word, but Googling it does bring up a few dictionary definitions (e.g., [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Indophobia)), a [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Indian_sentiment) (where it’s used synonymously with the main title, “Anti-Indian sentiment”), and usages by media outlets like the BBC and Huffington Post.

More importantly, both [the combining form *Indo-*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indo) and [the suffix *-phobia*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/phobia_1) are common enough to be widely recognised, so any competent English speaker should know immediately what you mean if you use it.

At any rate, I am not aware of any other words more commonly used to describe this.

Comment: Browsing the Internet, you do come across the word **"Indiaphobe."** For example on the website of the [Australian Cat Ladies](https://australianchristianlobby.org/contact-the-australian-cat-ladies/#comment-396) there is this sentence... >I hate Indian food, doesn’t mean I hate Indians or I’m an Indiaphobe and you can’t force me to like it as you do with everyone who opposes your beliefs.

Comment: That seems legit...

Comment: While I think this is the most legitimate suggestion, it's definitely not the clearest or most easily understood. Where I live, we would probably need to clarify if the speaker meant India or Indonesia.

Comment: @yuzuki I may be biased (being an Indo-Europeanist), but I have never heard of anyone using _Indo-_ to refer to Indonesia. A combining form of _Indonesia_ would have to be something like _Indoneso-_ or _Indonesio-_, if it exists at all.

Comment: I also do acknowledge possible biases (I live in Asia). While nothing comes to mind for 'Indo' being used as a consistent prefix to refer to Indonesia, which I attribute more to history than anything else, I do offer Indofoods (an Indonesian company) as an example. An 'Indonesio' prefix is also highly unwieldy and makes less sense than other variations of India or Indian.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet in Dutch, Indo- predominantly refers to Indonesian rather than Indian. This is most likely caused by the fact that Indonesia was once a Dutch colony whereas we had a lot less interaction with India.

Comment: @Cronax.  The Indo- prefix indicates India and the Indian subcontinent.
Examples of words with Indo- prefix: Indology, Indologist, Indomania, Indophile and Indo-European.

Comment: The web link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo

Comment: @DineshKumarGarg That is exactly why I said it was the most 'legitimate' or 'proper' English usage. However, as mentioned, the 'Indo-' prefix can still be ambiguous to many (extremely competent) English speakers depending on factors such as location, which I feel is important to consider because in the end, language is dictated by its users.

Comment: @DineshKumarGarg I know about what the prefix signifies in English, I was just providing JanusBahsJacquet with an example of people that refer to "Indo' to reference Indonesia rather than India

Answer (score 4):

***India-hater*** appears to be a term recently used in papers and on the net:

> [Why are Modi haters turning into India haters](http://www.opindia.com/2015/03/why-are-modi-haters-turning-into-india-haters/)?
>
> [Message to India-haters: Five reasons we don't give a damn](http://www.firstpost.com/ideas/message-to-india-haters-five-reasons-we-dont-give-a-damn-51988.html)
>
> - I am an India hater. And I don't do it for foolishness as many 'india lovers' would think of. [Yahoo Answers](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090412164928AAWm98V)

Comment: Why in the world would anyone rely in Yahoo, btw ;)

Comment: It is just a colloquial usage example, confirmed by papers.

Comment: @user36790 I think Yahoo Answers is sort of like Stack Exchange but without all the knowledgeable users and without moderation? lol

Comment: @Fiksdal A more general SE, but... WITHOUT MODERATION!! Only **flags** help there, no, there are no "mods", there are "flag checkers". No, post something bad, and *one day someone will flag it!* Lazy, LAZY people.